# ajax не выполняет succes

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Вот код js

```
$.get('fact_data.json')
            .done(succesFunction)
            .fail(ajaxFail);


    function succesFunction(jsonObj) {
        var data = "fact_data.json";
        var dataObj = json.parse(data);
        fact.style.border = '1px solid #e8e8e8';
        var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
        var txt = dataObj.facts.fact[n];
        fact.innerHTML = responseText;
    }

    function ajaxFail(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Fail: " + jqXHR.responseJSON);

        console.log("readyState: " + jqXHR.readyState);
        console.log("responseText: " + jqXHR.responseText);
        console.log("status: " + jqXHR.status);
        fact.innerHTML = 'Произошла ошибка при запросе';
    }
```

Вот json

```
{
"facts": [{
    "fact": "Российские пользователи фотографируют больше,чем любая другая европейская нация: в среднем за месяц наши соотечественники делают до 50 снимков. "
}, {
    "fact": "Россияне и французы больше всех следят за качеством фотографий."
}, {
    "fact": "В отличие от европейцев, россияне привыкли печатать фотографии, особенно те, которые сделаны во время отдыха, а также семейные и детские снимки."
}]
```

}

При выводе alert пишет "undefined", в консоли никаких ошибок нет, кроме responseText: undefined. Уже битый час не могу найти решение

Comment: textStatus, errorThrown ?? Что такое `json.parse`?